# How can I delete rows from table connected with foreign key?

Tags: mysql, innodb

I have table Songs with columns(ID_Song, Title, ID_Artist, ID_Image, ID_Audio) where ID_Artist, ID_Image, ID_Audio are foreign key.

Table Artists with columns (ID_Artist, Name)
Table Images with columns (ID_Image,filename, extension, size)
Table Audios with columns (ID_Audio,filename, extension, size)

Columns songs.ID_Artist references Artists.ID_Artist, songs.ID_Image references Images.ID_Image and songs.ID_Audio references Audios.ID_Audio, so when I delete a row from table Songs I want the data connected with that row from other tables be deleted as well, but I can't because of the foreign key, is there a way to do it?

Table Songs

```
CREATE TABLE `songs` (
 `ID_Song` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `SongTitle` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
 `ID_Artist` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `ID_Img` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `ID_SongFile` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `Approved` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
 PRIMARY KEY (`ID_Song`),
 KEY `ID_Artist` (`ID_Artist`),
 KEY `ID_SongFile` (`ID_SongFile`),
 KEY `ID_Img` (`ID_Img`),
 CONSTRAINT `songs_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`ID_Artist`) REFERENCES `artists` (`ID_Artist`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
 CONSTRAINT `songs_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`ID_SongFile`) REFERENCES `files` (`ID_File`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
 CONSTRAINT `songs_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`ID_Img`) REFERENCES `images` (`ID_Img`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Table Images

```
CREATE TABLE `images` (
 `ID_Img` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
 `extension` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
 `size` float NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`ID_Img`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: This doesn't translate well can you add your table definitions please.

Comment: @P.Salmon I updated, let me know if it is clear now

Comment: You can SHOW CREATE TABLE <tablename> then cut and paste the result to the question. I cannot tell for the question as is which are referencing and which are referenced tables.

Comment: This is a strange requirement. You want to delete the parent row, just because one of it's child rows is removed.

Comment: @P.Salmon I did it let me know if that is enough

Comment: @PaulSpiegel I want to do it only on the table images and audios because the relation is 1-1 but not with the table artists

Comment: Your FKs might be the wrong way around. I'd say that a song file should reference a song. Not sure about images though. However - you can select and save the FKs into variables. Delete the song. Then delete the image and file rows using the FKs in variables.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel maybe it would be better to just put all in one table images, songs, and files and just add artist as a foreign key?

Comment: You can delete songs any time you like since it is not referenced by any other table, and if you delete images the on delete cascade on FK `songs_ibfk_3` will delete songs. Am I missing something in your requirement?

Comment: @RayPember this is possible. But I'm not sure, if I would do that.

Comment: @P.Salmon If you delete an *image* together with the *song*, the *file* will still be there.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel yea I am moving uploaded files to a folder so later I will check how can I remove files from a folder using php

Comment: @RayPember I mean the row in `files` table.

Answer (score 0):

For the given schema, you need to fetch `ID_SongFile` and `ID_Img` before you delete a song. Assuming you want to delete the song with ID=123. In pure SQL it could be:

```
select ID_SongFile, ID_Img into @file_id, @img_id
from songs
where ID_Song = 123;

delete from songs where ID_Song = 123;

delete from images where ID_Img = @img_id;

delete from files where ID_File = @file_id;
```

Depending on your data logic, it might be better to "reverse" the relation. If files and images are only related to songs, and it's always a one-to-one relation, I would remove the `ID_SongFile` and `ID_Img` columns from the `songs` table and have a `ID_Song` column as foreign key in `images` and `files` tables. If you define those new FKs with `ON DELETE CASCADE`, you would just need to delete the song, and the related file and image will "disappear".

You could also just store all image and file information in the `songs` table. But IMHO having the columns `image_name`, `image_extension`, `image_size`, `file_name`, `file_extension` and `file_size` doesn't look very good. But there is nothing really wrong with that design.

Comment: ye, I had to change my design a bit but since images and files will always be 1-1 with songs I added those columns to the song table and removed the other tables.

Comment: because the way it was I couldn't delete just like that, I got error

Comment: As I wrote: reverse the relation, and you shouldn't get that error.